# Error when trying to deposit ERC20 token into smart contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity

This is the code I've been using, I simply want to be able to deposit tokens into a smart contract and allow the owner to withdraw. I am not sure how to modify this to allow the owner to withdraw the stored tokens inside the smart contract, can anyone help me out?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

interface USDC {

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

}

contract transferUSDc {
    USDC public USDc;
    address owner;
    mapping(address => uint) public stakingBalance;

    constructor() {
        USDc = USDC(0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function depositTokens(uint $USDC) public {

        // amount should be > 0
        
        // transfer USDC to this contract
        USDc.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), $USDC * 10 ** 6);
        
        // update staking balance
        stakingBalance[msg.sender] = stakingBalance[msg.sender] + $USDC * 10 ** 6;
    }

    // Unstaking Tokens (Withdraw)
    function withdrawalTokens(address _addressChange) public {
        // requires withdrawal tokens function to only be called by creator of contract
        require (msg.sender == owner);

        // reset balance to 0
        stakingBalance[_addressChange] = 0;
    }
    function checkBalance(address _address) public view returns (uint) {
        return stakingBalance[_address];
    }

    function ownerWithdrawal(uint _amount) public {
        require (msg.sender == owner);
        USDc.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _amount * 10 ** 6);
    }

}
```

I've tried modifying the contract, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *how to modify this to allow the owner to withdraw the stored tokens inside the smart contract*

You can invoke the `transfer()` function on the token contract from your contract. The token sender is the caller of the `transfer()` function, which is your contract.

```
function withdrawalTokens(address _addressChange) public {
    require (msg.sender == owner);

    // to prevent reentrancy attack
    uint256 amountToWithdraw = stakingBalance[_addressChange];

    stakingBalance[_addressChange] = 0;

    // transfer
    // from this contract address (caller of `transfer()`)
    // to the caller of the `withdrawalTokens()` function (the `owner` address)
    USDc.transfer(msg.sender, amountToWithdraw);
}
```